# Add a node in a gridpane using mouse

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to do a quite easy boardgame (Carcassonne) but I'm having a lot of troubles with the graphic interface. The problem is that I don't see the way to make a relation between the mouse clicks and the gridpane row and columns.

The first tile is given and it's always added to the 100, 100 gridpanes position. You won't see it in the code, but for each tile added if the adjacents are empty it's added a white tile, so it looks like this:

[image]

Then, the player is expected to do a legal move ( we're not controlling cheaters, so yeah, it will be a weak game ) in the positions x = 99 y = 100, x = 101 y = 100, x = 100 y = 99, x = 100 y = 101.

But when i click there using the method play() the e.getSceneX(); method returns me the pixel position, and I need a way to convert it to a valid row index. So this is happening:

[image]

This is the console output:

tile XCCCC added at 100 100 // this is always given by the program, it's always the same
tile MFFCF added at 391 380

In this case, I clicked to the x = 100 y = 101 gridpane but the mouse returned me the pixel 391, 380.

Any idea?

This is the structure of my code:

```
public final class GUI extends Application {

private Game _game;
private GridPane _visualBoard;

@Override
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
    // some stuff setting the gridpane, which will be inside a scrollpane and the scrollpane will be inside a borderpane which will alse have 2 additional VBoxes with the current turn information
    play();
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}

public void play() {
    _visualBoard.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent e) -> {
        double x = e.getSceneX();
        double y = e.getSceneY();
        _game.doMove(x, y);
    });
}

 public void insertTile(myTile r, int x, int y) {
    myVisualTile rV = new myVisualTile(r);
    _visualBoard.add(rV, x, y);
}
```

And this is the class game:

```
public class Game {

private GUI _gui;
private List<Player> _players; // An arraylist of players
private int _currentPlayer; // The index of the current player in the ArrayList
private Board _board; // The logical board, totally separeted from the gridpane
private tileStack _stack;

 public void doMove(double x, double y) {
    int ax = (int) x;
    int ay = (int) y;
    if (_stack.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Game finnished");
        //stuff
    }
    else {
        myTile r = _stack.poll(); // takes the first tile of the stack
        _gui.insertTile(r, ax, ay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `_visualBoard.getRowIndex(node)` and `_visualBoard.getColumnIndex(node)`?

Comment: Also, learn [`Java's Naming Conventions`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html). This can be very important when dealing with `JavaFX` components.

Comment: And how can I select that node?

Comment: I am guessing that you want to give that node focus? Maybe you could use some `CSS` tricks?

Comment: I have tried to select the clicked node using Node soure = (node) event.getSource(). But does dont work. If only I had a way to know in which node I clicked i would know the gridpane position

Comment: I may not be understanding your purpose correctly, but why are you trying to catch the exact coordinates of the mouse click? Why not just listen for the clicks on each individual tiles (whether it's empty or not)? Then calling the `GridPane.getColumnIndex()` will get you that tile's column.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void play() {
        _visualBoard.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent e) -> {
            Node source = (Node)e.getTarget() ;
            Integer x = GridPane.getColumnIndex(source);
            Integer y = GridPane.getRowIndex(source);

            _game.doMove(x, y);
        });
}
```

That actualy worked. Thanks everybody!